# BigDecimal issue with long and lat

Tags: java, groovy, latitude-longitude, bigdecimal

I have an address domain , which has fields lat and long as BigDecimal and i am using constraints of scale as 16. I have this address

```
550 Tremont St, Boston, MA 02116, USA
```

its long and lat are -71.07126540000002 and 42.3438919

Longitude for this address is stored in db as  -71.0712654000000200. now i need to compare the saved longitude with any new request to check if longitude already exist.

I am sending the same longitude again -71.07126540000002 but i am not able to convert it the form as it saved in db (-71.0712654000000200) before comparing as they are the long. of same address.

i tried using

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(-71.07126540000002)
println a.setScale(16,  RoundingMode.CEILING)​ // tried all other RoundingMode
```

but all are giving response as either -71.0712654000000156 or -71.0712654000000157 but not getting  -71.0712654000000200

Help!

Comment: It appears to me that both values have 7 digits of precision and the rest is just error. Round to 16 decimal places isn't appropriate when you have 15-16 digits of precision.

Comment: Do this for exact representation: `BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("-71.07126540000002")`. Doubles have no exact representation for the decimal part.

Comment: It's a bit ridiculous to look for an exact match. The numbers you have given are several orders of magnitude less than a micrometer apart. For all practical reasons that's the same location.

Comment: Even at the equator, 5 decimal places are accurate to about a metre. Do you really need more accuracy than this? (AKA I'm willing to bet your values you have for the location are nothing like as precise as you are suggesting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be used

```
a.setScale(14, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

since after 14th pos. zeros are not significative

at the end will be **-71.07126540000002**

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use BigDecimal notation:

​`-71.0712654000000200000g​.setScale(16)` or `​-71.07126540000002000000G.setScale(16)`

Both result in:

`-71.0712654000000200`

Another option is setting a custom [MathContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html).