# How to get the value without round up/down in Java?

Tags: java, double, primitive-types

```
double d0 = Double.parseDouble("53.82233040000000557");
double d1 = Double.valueOf("53.82233040000000557");
```

output

```
d0 = 53.822330400000006
d1 = 53.822330400000006
```

Comment: @hc_dev thanks for the heads up I had misread the title (biased reading, as I'm in the middle of typing up some Js)

Answer (score 4):

#### Precision Numbers in Java

Class `java.math.BigDecimal` is better **for handling numbers where precision matters** (like *monetary amounts*), see [BigDecimal VS double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal).

It could be used for [geo-coordinates (latitude/longitude)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216477/bigdecimal-issue-with-long-and-lat). Although practitionars argue that [`double` is precise enough for lat./long.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754881/java-double-vs-bigdecimal-for-latitude-longitude) - since you don't want to locate something at nano-meter scale.

#### Example Code

If you need high precision and scale for your number, use `BigDecimal` like this:

```
BigDecimal decimalValue = new BigDecimal("53.82233040000000557");
System.out.println("as BigDecimal: " + decimalValue.toPlainString());
// prints exactly: 53.82233040000000557
```

Run this code online (IDE one): [Double VS BigDecimal for high precision](https://ideone.com/zZTPdJ)

#### Read more

Read more in a tutorial on [Java: BigDecimal and BigInteger](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bigdecimal-biginteger)

Answer (score 2):

If you need precision, you have to use a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Since this is a new contributor, some usage hints or a code-example might be helpful. Otherwise this _single sentence_ would rather be worth a comment ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that *you cannot.*  The values you are getting are the most accurate approximation to your values that can possibly be stored in a `double`.  There is no possible way to get a more accurate, less rounded value stored in a `double`.

If you require that the answers are not rounded at all, therefore, you should not be using `double`.  The data type you should be using instead is `BigDecimal`.